# Populate datalist dynamically using Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to populate a datalist dynamically using declarative HTML. The idea is using a datalist to pick states, but also have the user be able to type into the input so narrow the results. A `<datalist>` was the path of least resistance, yet I am running into some issues.

Below is my basic template structure.

**HTML**

```
<input list="stateSelection">
<datalist id="stateSelection" class="stateList">
  <template for:each={stateOptions} for:item="state">
    <option key={state.id} value={state.value}>{state.label}</option>
  </template>
</datalist>
```

**JS**

Below is my basic javascript.

```js
export default class RadioGroupBasic extends LightningElement {

    stateOptions = [
        { label: 'Alabama', value: 'AL', id: 'AL' },
        { label: 'Alaska', value: 'AK', id: 'AK' },
        { label: 'Arizona', value: 'AZ', id: 'AZ' },
        { label: 'Arkansas', value: 'AR', id: 'AR' },
        { label: 'California', value: 'CA', id: 'CA' },
        { label: 'Colorado', value: 'CO', id: 'CO' },
        { label: 'Connecticut', value: 'CT', id: 'CT' },
        { label: 'Delaware', value: 'DE', id: 'DE' },
        { label: 'Florida', value: 'FL', id: 'FL' },
        { label: 'Georgia', value: 'GA', id: 'GA' },
        { label: 'Hawaii', value: 'HI', id: 'HI' },
        { label: 'Idaho', value: 'ID', id: 'ID' },
        { label: 'Ilinois', value: 'IL', id: 'IL' },
        { label: 'Indiana', value: 'IN', id: 'IN' },
        { label: 'Iowa', value: 'IA', id: 'IA' },
        { label: 'Kansas', value: 'KS', id: 'KS' },
        { label: 'Kentucky', value: 'KY', id: 'KY' },
        { label: 'Lousiana', value: 'LA', id: 'LA' },
        { label: 'Maine', value: 'ME', id: 'ME' },
        { label: 'Marryland', value: 'MD', id: 'MD' },
        { label: 'Massachusettes', value: 'MA', id: 'MA' },
        { label: 'Michigan', value: 'MI', id: 'MI' },
        { label: 'Minnesota', value: 'MN', id: 'MN' },
        { label: 'Mississippi', value: 'MS', id: 'MS' },
        { label: 'Missouri', value: 'MO', id: 'MO' },
        { label: 'Montana', value: 'MT', id: 'MT' },
        { label: 'Nebraska', value: 'NE', id: 'NE' },
        { label: 'Nevada', value: 'NV', id: 'NV' },
        { label: 'New Hamshire', value: 'NH', id: 'NH' },
        { label: 'New Jersey', value: 'NJ', id: 'NJ' },
        { label: 'New Mexico', value: 'NM', id: 'NM' },
        { label: 'New York', value: 'NY', id: 'NY' },
        { label: 'North Carolina', value: 'NC', id: 'NC' },
        { label: 'North Dakota', value: 'ND', id: 'ND' },
        { label: 'Ohio', value: 'OH', id: 'OH' },
        { label: 'Oklahoma', value: 'OK', id: 'OK' },
        { label: 'Oregon', value: 'OR', id: 'OR' },
        { label: 'Pennsylvania', value: 'PA', id: 'PA' },
        { label: 'Rhode Island', value: 'RI', id: 'RI' },
        { label: 'South Carolina', value: 'SC', id: 'SC' },
        { label: 'South Dakota', value: 'SD', id: 'SD' },
        { label: 'Tennessee', value: 'TN', id: 'TN' },
        { label: 'Texas', value: 'TX', id: 'TX' },
        { label: 'Utah', value: 'UT', id: 'UT' },
        { label: 'Vermont', value: 'VT', id: 'VT' },
        { label: 'Virginia', value: 'VA', id: 'VA' },
        { label: 'Washington', value: 'WA', id: 'WA' },
        { label: 'West Virginia', value: 'WV', id: 'WV' },
        { label: 'Wisconson', value: 'WI', id: 'WI' },
        { label: 'Wyoming', value: 'WY', id: 'WY' },
        { label: 'District of Columbia', value: 'DC', id: 'DC' }
    ];
}
```

Yet this doesn't work for creating `<option>` tags. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Nate, and welcome to SFSE. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? what is rendering, what's the experience?

Comment: Also, I see that `stateOptions` is not decorated. Have you tried adding a `@track` decorator?

Comment: @SebastianKessel The input renders, but none of the options appear, so I just have an empty input element.

Comment: Nate, Renji has the right answer below for you. I added a link to a potential solution, so you will probably want to explore that.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use id selectors in LWC - ids are modified at runtime by the framework.
Therefore you can`t use html5 datalists (because the input uses an id selector and will not find the element)  and you need to build a custom one

Edit: As highlighted by Sebastian you could potentially use a workaround by setting  the list value manually to the element id as described [here](https://blog.enree.co/2019/04/salesforce-lwc-autocomplete-magic-with-html-datalist.html).
(I personally would be cautious though because such workarounds always hold the risk of quirks as you are now responsible for rehydrating the template and values by your own)

Comment: Renji, you probably want to offer a solution as well. I found a possible one here: https://blog.enree.co/2019/04/salesforce-lwc-autocomplete-magic-with-html-datalist.html , feel free to draw from it

Comment: The work around was exactly what I need. Thank you.